# Apex Trigger Preventing Contact Deletion

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an Apex Trigger on my Contact object that is preventing me from deleting any Contacts.

When attempting to delete a Contact, I receive the following error prompt:

```
"There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help."
```

I also receive an email from ApexApplication:

```
Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization: [...]/[...]
Source organization: [...] (null)
setAccountFieldViaContact: execution of AfterDelete

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

()
```

The code for my Apex Trigger is included below:

```
trigger setAccountFieldViaContact on Contact (after INSERT, after UPDATE, after DELETE, after UNDELETE) {

    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    Account[] updateAccounts = new Account[0];
    Map<Id, String> error = new Map<Id, String>();

    // Find all account Id values
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
    }

    accountIds.remove(null);

    // Abort early if no accounts to process
    if(accountIds.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    for(Account record: [
            SELECT (SELECT Custom_Contact_Field__c FROM Contacts
                    WHERE Criteria__c = TRUE
                    LIMIT 1)
            FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountIds]) {
        updateAccounts.add(
            new Account(
                Id = record.Id, 
                Custom_Account_Field__c = (record.Contacts.isEmpty()?null:record.Contacts[0].Custom_Contact_Field__c)
                ));
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(updateAccounts, false);
```

Any ideas would be tremendously helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code was that you were using trigger.new in both insert and delete operations. 
So, you need to use trigger.new and trigger.old separately for both operations.

Here is your modified code:-
The problem in your code was that you were using trigger.new in both insert and delete operations. 
So, you need to use trigger.new and trigger.old separately for both operations.

Here is modified code:-

```
trigger setAccountFieldViaContact on Contact (after INSERT, after UPDATE, before DELETE, after UNDELETE)
{

    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    Account[] updateAccounts = new Account[0];
    Map<Id, String> error = new Map<Id, String>();
    //system.debug('::::::::::::;'+trigger.oldmap);
    // Find all account Id values
    if(trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
            accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isdelete){
        for(Contact record: Trigger.old) {
            accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
        }
    }

    accountIds.remove(null);

    // Abort early if no accounts to process
    if(accountIds.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    for(Account record: [SELECT (SELECT Custom_Contact_Field__c FROM Contacts
                                 WHERE Criteria__c = TRUE
                                 LIMIT 1)
                         FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountIds]) {
                             updateAccounts.add( new Account(
                                 Id = record.Id, 
                                 Custom_Account_Field__c = (record.Contacts.isEmpty()?null:record.Contacts[0].Custom_Contact_Field__c)
                             ));
                         }

    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(updateAccounts, false);}
```

Regards,
Suraj

Comment: Thank you, Suraj - I noticed that the first block includes `trigger.` || `Trigger.` One is lowercase and one is uppercase. does the capitalization make a difference here? Also, are there any other trigger contexts that I need other than `isInsert`,`isUpdate`,and `isDelete`?

Comment: NO, capitalization doesn't make a difference as apex is case insensitive and you do not need other trigger contexts .

Answer (score 2):

The error is because when trigger runs in after delete operation it will give an error in section

```
for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
}
```

It will give an error because there is no trigger.new context variable available in after delete and before delete operation so it will give an error of Attempt to de-reference a null object.

So you have to check isDelete before this condition.
Maybe this solution will help you.

Comment: Thank you, Ram - so I would wrap the `for(Contact record: Trigger.new){ ... }` block in an if statement that checks if the trigger is `isDelete`?

Comment: yes @Brandon, I think that's the issue with this code. You can do it in the way Mahood tell. 
because I also think helper is the best way to write the trigger and passing context variable in it as per your condition.

Answer (score 2):

Two things that could be problematic here:

1. `WHERE Id = :accountIds` should be `WHERE Id IN :accountIds`
2. You are not using [trigger contexts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) variables, e.g. trigger.isInsert, etc, which means, that for **after delete** event `trigger.new` will have nothing. Hence the error.

**Solution**

- Isolate your code blocks in **trigger contexts**, ideally, use a trigger framework/handler class to make your triggers logic less. Check the [considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm) for using trigger context variables as well.

Comment: Thank you Mahmood. If I wrap the code block in a trigger context for `isDelete` wont that prevent the code that follows from functioning properly I would assume I need that part for the trigger to work.

Comment: So, here is the thing- `trigger.new` will be nothing in case of `after delete` event. So, your existing code which relies on `trigger.new` will not work. You need to devise your logic for different events in different code blocks, separated by trigger context variables offcourse.